# "Hello world" in C without printf?

Tags: c

Is it possible to write a "hello world" program in C without the use of the printf function? (while still keeping the program relatively at a few lines)

Comment: You can always use puts, fwrite, etc.

Comment: `write(1,"hello world",11);`

Comment: @technosaurus: That is not part of C standard, but may be part of other standard...

Comment: `system("echo Hello world!");` :P

Comment: better read for different print functions available

Comment: @nhahtdh: It's part of POSIX.

Comment: @nhtahtdh: perhaps you can name a system where write doesn't exist.  I can't.  Win32 has it in io.h and it is in linux, bsd, solaris and everything I have used and it is typically a system call - thus low overhead.

Comment: @Alvin, don't make me come over there and slap you around :-)

Comment: @technosaurus, if it's not in the ISO C standard, it's not C. Feel free however to add tags posix/linux/unix/whatever :-)

Comment: Yes, it is a posix standard, but it has worked in most everything with the right (non-iso standard) headers, but to answer my own question apparently wince does not ship with io.h

Comment: @AlvinWong That makes program pretty slow and using system(); is not a good idea.

Answer (score 7):

This should work:

```
int main (void)
{
    puts("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}
```

Why don't you want to use `printf`? I can't think of any reason not to.

Comment: It's not that I don't want to use it, it was sort of a "is it possible to do" question because I'm new to C.

Comment: Actually, if your use case is just a normal string with a linefeed at the end, it makes more sense to _not_ use `printf`. `puts` is almost certainly more efficient since it doesn't have to worry about formatting characters. +1, once the `main` was changed to one of the canonical forms :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo I've seen GCC optimizing `printf("string literal");` into `puts("string literal");`. I found that out because it broke my attempt to hijack `printf()` using dynamic library injection :O

Comment: `puts` adds a `'\n'` to the printed string, so `printf("string literal")` isn't equivalent to `puts("string literal")`.  However, `printf("string literal")` => `fputs("string literal", stdout)` is a safe substitution.

Answer (score 5):

Well, if we're going to include silly examples (yes, I'm looking at you, technosauraus), I'd go with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void makeItSo (char *str) {
    if (*str == '\0') return;
    makeItSo (str + 1);
    putchar (*str);
}

int main (void) {
    makeItSo ("\ndlrow olleH");
    return 0;
}
```

Just don't do this for really long strings or you'll find out what Stack Overflow *really* means :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
write(STDOUT_FILENO, "hello world", strlen("hello world"));
```

Comment: Err, `stdout` is a _stream,_ not a file descriptor. Perhaps you meant `fwrite`? Especially since there is no `write` in C per se.

Comment: Hrm, right. Change stdout to number 1. Thx.

Comment: or 2 to write to stderr, and included unistd.h for write and string.h for strlen (or just put the integer value since it is a constant string)

Comment: screw it. let's do it in assembly! :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a ridiculous alternative to just using `puts("hello world\n");`

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
  char *s="hello world\n";
  while (*s) putchar(*s++);
}
```